# In Gnuplot, how can I plot the sum of two columns when I'm plotting by header name

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have the following data file:

```
denst densu densd denss
3     1     1     1
4     1     1.5   1.5
5     1     2.5   1.5
```

I can plot, say, `densu`(`denst`) as:

`plot 'file.txt' u 'denst':'densu'`

Which is very convenient syntax. But if I want to plot, say, the sum of `densu` and `densd`, with respect to `denst` the only way I can do it is:

`set key autotitle columnhead` to tell gnuplot the first line is headers and not data

`plot 'file.txt' u 1:($2+$3)` to plot

The question is how can I do operations with column values like that, but using the name notation? The actual file is a csv with ~40 columns, and it's very tedious to manually count which column is which number so I can use the `$n` syntax to do math with column data.

I would want to do something like `plot 'file.txt' u 1:($'densu'+$'densd')`, using header name syntax analogously to how I can do it with column number syntax. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've discovered a way to do it. These two commands are equivalent:

```
plot 'file.txt' u 1:($2+$3)
plot 'file.txt' u 1:(column(2)+column(3))
```

You can't do

```
plot 'file.txt' u 'denst':($'densu'+$'densd')
```

but you can do

```
plot 'file.txt' u 'denst':(column('densu')+column('densd'))
```

to the same effect.